# Неверное сообщение об ошибке в ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net

Делаю валидацию, добавил такие атрибуты к модели:

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Add phone name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Add phone model.")]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Add phone memory.")]
    [Range(0, 512, ErrorMessage = "Memory size must be between 0 and 512!")]
    public int Memory { get; set; }
}
```

Если отправляю ошибочную модель, то сообщения об ошибках у `string` такие же, как у меня в модели, но у `int` нет. Вот такое сообщение у пустого свойства `Memory`:

> **Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'Memory',**
>   **line 1, position 33.**

Почему сообщение не ***Add phone memory.***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделай свойство `Memory` nullable:

```
public int? Memory { get; set; }
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!